# ToolTip appearing but not appearing again unless mouse moves

Tags: c#, winforms, tooltip

I am using TextChanged event on a textbox to validate the contents. I am trying to make a tooltip appear if the user keys in illegal characters. This works fine the first time an illegal character is keyed in. IF I delete the illegal character and then add another illegal character the tooltip does not reappear. I have to move the mouse for the tooltip to reappear.

What I want is a way to commulicate to the user that they have entered an illegal character in a textbox that cannot be used in a path.

Why does the tooltip not reappear after another illegal character is entered?

Code:

```
    // Initialization
    char[] illegalCharacters = Path.GetInvalidPathChars();

    //Event handler
    private void descriptionTextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (description.Text.Length < 6)
        {
            description.BackColor = Color.LightPink;
            toolTip1.SetToolTip(description, @"Must be at least 6 characters long.");
        }
        else
        {
            description.BackColor = Color.White;
            foreach (char illegalCharacter in illegalCharacters)
            {
                if (description.Text.Contains(illegalCharacter))
                {
                    description.BackColor = Color.LightPink;
                    toolTip1.RemoveAll();
                    toolTip1.Show(@"Name may not contain a '< , > | or double quote.", description);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: How about changing the background color of textbox in case of illegal value?!

Comment: I'm already doing that. I also want to educate the user as to what is wrong with the value instead of just flagging it.

Comment: See the [ErrorProvider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.errorprovider) Class.

Comment: @Jimi - Thank you, that worked great! Looks like someone already thought this problem out very well.